# Issue with zbar qrcode scanner (Randomly scanning?)

Tags: android

I'm using the zbar QR code scanner in one of my apps and it's scanning all QR codes correctly , but my issue is that quite frequently **it scans and beeps as if its detecting a QR code, when there's no QR code there**. So for instance I'll have it about 3-5 inches away from my desk, then after a few minutes of writing code, it will beep and go through the scanned QR code process...

Has anyone who's had experience with zbar had this happen? It's very odd and I'm considering switching to a different QR code library.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Been experiencing this ourselves with several different bar-code scanning libraries and haven't been able to find a solution other than verifying the scanned code lies within our expected bar code boundaries. Definitely not ideal.

Comment: Sometimes I am facing the same issue,so if you find any solutions please share it here

Comment: Same happening to me, it seems that in some devices it happens more often, in others it doesn't. It seems that it reads a random 8 digit int

Answer (score 0):

**use these lines of code for one time scan**

```
public void scanSendQRCode() {

    startQRScanner();
    Toast.makeText(this, "scan QR Button clicked! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


//qr code scan Action-based

private void startQRScanner() {
    new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan();
}
```

*don't forget to add:*

> implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'